# Javascript - How to return a partial array from a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to insert in the middle of a columns array, many elements based on a parameter returned by the function **getSpecificColumns(parameter)**.

The first one is working cause it is returning a single object, but is there any way to return many elements in the middle of the array?

```
$scope.getSpecificColumns = function (myParam) {
    return { field: "SpecificField1", format: "{0:c}" };
}

$scope.getSpecificColumnsNotWorking = function (myParam) {
    return { field: "SpecificField2", format: "{0:c}" },
           { field: "SpecificField3", format: "{0:c}" };
}  

$scope.positionMontantNavGridOptions = {
    height: 630,
    filterable: {
        mode: "row"
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "Field1", width: "200px" },
        { field: "Field2", title: "Field 2", width: "80px" },        
        getSpecificColumns(parameter),
        { field: "Field4" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see arrays in your code

Comment: @hindmost Seems to be confusing maps and arrays. Although, I guess objects are implemented as hashmaps, which use arrays, so I guess they are technically associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return an array, return an array:

```
$scope.getSpecificColumnsNotWorking = function (myParam) {
  return [{ field: "SpecificField2", format: "{0:c}" },
          { field: "SpecificField3", format: "{0:c}" }];
}
```

A **expression** such as:

```
{ field: "SpecificField2", format: "{0:c}" },{ field: "SpecificField3", format: "{0:c}" };
```

evaluates to the former of the comma delimeted "sub-expressions", for example:

```js
var a = 1, b = 2;
var c = a, b;
alert(c === a);
```

and in your original code this directly translates to the first literal object being returned from the function while the later is "discarded".

(By the way, if you're not using the `myParam` argument you might as well not define it and not pass it in the call)

Answer (score 1):

First return array, then use `Array.prototype.concat` to flaten it into array.
Is this a suitable solution for your problem?

```
$scope.getSpecificColumnsNotWorking = function (myParam) {
    return [
        { field: "SpecificField2", format: "{0:c}" },
        { field: "SpecificField3", format: "{0:c}" }
    ];
}  

columns: [].concat(
    { field: "Field1", width: "200px" },
    { field: "Field2", title: "Field 2", width: "80px" },        
    getSpecificColumnsNotWorking (parameter),
    { field: "Field4" });
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.